# Reference module exported using “export =” in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, amd

Since TypeScript 0.9, you can set the exported value of an module directly using `export =`:

```
// client.ts 
class Client { 
    constructor(public name: string, public description: string) { } 
} 
export = Client;
```

Is there a way to reference `Client` using a `/// <reference ... />`?

The following does not expose the `Client` class:

```
/// <reference path="./client.ts" />

class SomeClass {
    addClient(client: Client) { // Could not find symbol 'Client'
        ...
    }
}
```

I guess this is the expected behavior since I'm exporting a direct reference to the `Client` class, so the module is basically anonymous. But in the above class I'm not actually instantiating a new `Client`, so adding `import Client = require('Client');` would let the AMD loader load `client.js` even though it would not be needed if `addClient` is never called.

So I was hoping for something like:

```
/// <reference path="./client.ts" export="Client" />
```

Where `export` would be the name to assign the module to.

Comment: When you use ``export =``, it is compiled to an AMD module.  Then it is an "external" module, which you must use the ``import foo = require("bar");`` syntax to import it.  JavaScript (and so TypeScript) cannot detect whether ``Client`` is actually used, and so the ``require`` call will be file-level.  If you want to have such flexibility, declare a ``Client`` interface in a ``.d.ts`` type definition file and then ``<reference>`` it.

Comment: Yeah I guess (aside from importing `Client`) this is the only option, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`/// <reference ... /` does not work when you have something exported at the file level (called `external modules` in typescript documentation)

Modify your code to be :

```
// client.ts 
class Client { 
    constructor(public name: string, public description: string) { } 
} 
// Remove this line export = Client;
```

**Further explanation:** The only way to access items in a file after you export anything at the file root level, is via the `import`/`require` combination.

PS: I made a video about internal / external typescript modules : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Yes, I am using requirejs. By using `export = ` I'm able to prevent anything being defined in the global scope.

I noticed I provided a bad example where I created a new instance of `Client`, in this case it would actually need the import. I edited my question to provide a case where `Client` might not be needed.

Comment: Oh and btw, I did watch 2 of your videos on YouTube on the subject. They did help me understand how TypeScript Modules work, thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks. Made my answer more explicit "The only way to access items in a file after you export anything at the file root level, is via the import/require combination". what you could do is move the class to a third file without an export, and use it from there

Comment: So the only way for me to assign `Client` to the parameter `client`, is to add an import? This would mean requirejs will always load `Client` when `SomeClass` is being loaded, even though this might not be necessary.

Comment: Yes. As an external module creates a namespace you can only import via require.

Comment: Okay thanks. I think it'll be a nice feature for TypeScript to be able to reference an external module.